# html - redirect to new url after form submission (django site)

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to make a button redirect the user to a new url after they submit a form. This is how it is right now, and it works properly and all the data gets sent to the django database.

```
<form method='POST' action='' class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-7" style="background-color: lightgreen; border-radius: 10px">
```

However, when I change the action to 
`action="{% url 'ridesharing:request-success' %}"`,
the redirect works, but the data does not go to my django database.

What is going on here?

Comment: I think you need to post some of the relevant view functions for us to help you...

Comment: you have to put the script that stores data in the database in the new url

Comment: post relevant views function, would help answer the question.

Comment: Show us the urls.py file from where this form is getting rendered and also share the views.py where you are handling form and form data. Then we can properly help you.

Comment: Why do you need to change the value of `action` attribute in your form ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some confusion here. The action of the form is where the browser will send the data. Obviously, if you don't point that at the view which actually processes the data, then it won't be saved.

To redirect after a post, your view should return a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a form with an empty action attribute:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
```

the POST data will be sent to **the same URL**. This is useful because if there is some error in the form, it's easy to re-display it with all fields filled with values entered by the user. Then, when the form becomes valid, a redirect is done to the confirmation page.

When you declare your form that way:

```
<form method='POST' action='{% url 'ridesharing:request-success' %}'>
```

The data entered by the user in the form will be sent to the view `request-success`. But this view probably only render the template of the confirmation page. If you want to correctly handle data from the form, you have to set `action` attribute of your `<form>` to the same view, or easier, keep it empty.

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand why Daniel Roseman's post isnt accepted as the answer. It helped me when I wanted to redirect a create form to its update form.

Basically in the view of the app I defined the get_success_url to reverse_lazy to the data-update.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('app_name:data-update')
```

Just replace the 'app_name:data-update' with the appropriate url.